# how to load images after everything else is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, css

i got some idea that to load a fake image on a div before original image finishies loading and that to be after winodws load.i got some code but cant understand in which part i have to put src image for fake image and original image.do help me out in this code .
my html part is

```
<div class="myimage"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></div>
```

note:Trick is to set the src attribute only when that source is loaded in temporary `img. $(img).load(fn);` handles that.

```
$(function(){
        $.each(document.images, function(){
                   var this_image = this;
                   var src = $(this_image).attr('src') || '' ;
                   if(!src.length > 0){
                       //this_image.src = options.loading; // show loading........
                       var lsrc = $(this_image).attr('lsrc') || '' ;
                       if(lsrc.length > 0){
                           var img = new Image();
                           img.src = lsrc;
                           $(img).load(function() {
                               this_image.src = this.src;
                           });
                       }
                   }
               });
      });
```

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` attribute to do it:

```
<div class="myimage"><img data-orig="original.jpg" src="fake.jpg" /></div>

$(window).load(function(){
  $('.myimage img').attr("src", $(this).data('orig')).removeAttr('data-orig');
});
```

Comment: thank you for comment can u re write the code for me along with html where to include  original.jpg and fake.jpg.can you rephrase the code. @Afshin Haghighat

Comment: it not showing original image except loading.gif although src replace with data-src but loading image still remain @Afshin Haghighat

Answer (score 0):

You can add your images url to a custom data-url attribute and make your image url a base64 1x1 gif. And then when the page loads completely you can get your url from it. Basically it will be like this.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="original-image.png" />

$(window).load(function() {

   $("img").each(function() {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
   });
});
```

Comment: it not showing original image except loading.gif although src replace with data-src but loading image still remain @UmurAlpay